# Where can I find udevd (daemon) source code

Tags: udev

I know that udev can be split to two parts:

1. libudev
2. udevd

To port udev to my platform, I have successfully done the libudev on my platform.

However, I need udevd, the daemon manages the virtual/dev.

I have searched around the source code for udevd but no progress so far.

Please let me know where I can download the source of udevd if you know any.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

udev is now part of [systemd](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/), but there is also a fork named [eudev](https://github.com/gentoo/eudev).

Comment: Thanks. So Is it possible only ports udevd instead of systemd on my platform?

Comment: Yes, just take `eudev`. In theory you should be also able to port systemd's `udev`, but I think `eudev` is better suited. Btw what platform are talking about?

Comment: Actually, I dont need udev, only daemon(udevd) I need. Does eudev play the same thing as udevd and is it compatible with udevd?

Comment: Yes, it is a direct fork with the same functionality. Do you know such embedded distro as [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)? It provides both `systemd`, `eudev` and even `mdev`. See the [documentation](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_dev_management).

Comment: Hey, yegorich, By running udevadm, will this check the availability of udevd first? Otherwise, it will get hanged. Is my understanding correct? thanks

Comment: I don't know the whole mechanism in details, so stop `udevd` and invoke `udevadm`.

Comment: if you are trying to port udev onto other platforms, udevd, udevadm and libudev will be needed.

Comment: I want only to download libudev source to compile it in android - to observe usb devices. I don't want udevadm and udevd. Will it work?